# I need to pass image from adapter to activity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

In the adapter code, I used the normal intent. I know that this isn't the proper way to do it. But still I want to know the approach.

Adapter code

```
holder.rlContent.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, RestaurantMenuActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("restaurantId", restaurant.restaurantId)
            intent.putExtra("restaurantName", holder.txtRestaurantName.text.toString())
            intent.putExtra("restaurantImage",holder.restaurantImage.toString())
            intent.putExtra("restaurantPrice",holder.txtRestaurantPrice.toString())
            intent.putExtra("restaurantRating",holder.txtRestaurantRating.toString())
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
```

In the activity code, I got the image like this :

```
val bundle: Bundle? = intent.extras
        bundle?.getString("restaurantImage")?.let {
            Picasso.get().load(it).error(R.drawable.restaurant_image)
                .into(restaurantImage)
```

This always displays the error image and not the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing in your code is that you are converting the actual views that are being rendered into strings and passing them to the next activity. You should be passing the values that you are setting in those views instead.

```
//This is wrong. This is converting the views into strings 
//and passing them to the next activity which is useless
val intent = Intent(context, RestaurantMenuActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("restaurantId", restaurant.restaurantId)
intent.putExtra("restaurantName", holder.txtRestaurantName.text.toString())
intent.putExtra("restaurantImage",holder.restaurantImage.toString())
intent.putExtra("restaurantPrice",holder.txtRestaurantPrice.toString())
intent.putExtra("restaurantRating",holder.txtRestaurantRating.toString())
context.startActivity(intent)

//Do this instead - Notice I changed holder.* to your actual restaurant object
val intent = Intent(context, RestaurantMenuActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("restaurantId", restaurant.restaurantId)
intent.putExtra("restaurantName", restaurant.name)
intent.putExtra("restaurantImage",restaurant.image.toString())
intent.putExtra("restaurantPrice", restaurant.price.toString())
intent.putExtra("restaurantRating", restaurant.rating.toString())
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
    var imageUrl=""
    if( intent.extras != null) {
        imageUrl= intent.getStringExtra("restaurantImage")
    }
    
    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).error(R.drawable.restaurant_image)
            .into(restaurantImage)
```

Comment: Still the same error image is shown @SandeepPareek

Comment: check url is valid or not (use Debug or Logcat) and if you use Instagram share me userName as a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `holder.restaurant_imageview` instead pass the your image URL from the model class.
also make sure you are doing this in your  `onBindViewHolder`

```
val restaurantItem = getItem(position)

// check if the item is not null

if(restaurantItem != null) {

   // share the data via intent from here

    val intent = Intent(context, RestaurantMenuActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("restaurantId", restaurant.restaurantId)
    intent.putExtra("restaurantName", restaurant.name)
    intent.putExtra("restaurantImage",restaurant.image.toString())
    intent.putExtra("restaurantPrice", restaurant.price.toString())
    intent.putExtra("restaurantRating", restaurant.rating.toString())
    context.startActivity(intent)
```

}